# pandas to_dict with python native datetime type and not timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame`  `df` that contains `Timesatamp` columns.

I wish to create an iterator of rows (either via the `iter..` methods or via `to_dict`) from `df` where the `Timesatamp` values are python `datetime`.

I have tried doing this

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(['datetime']):
        df[col] = df[col].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

however it seems like the columns is still `Timesatamp` when using the above mentioned iterator methods.
Is there a **'batch'y** way to achieve this apart from manualy converting each values when its iterated upon?

---

**example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='12h', periods=2), 'a':[1,2]})
for col in df.select_dtypes(['datetime']):
    df[col] = df[col].dt.to_pydatetime()
print(df.to_dict('records'))
```

the output:

```
[{'d': Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 'a': 1}, {'d': Timestamp('2018-01-01 12:00:00'), 'a': 2}]
```

the desired output:

```
[{'d': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'a': 1}, {'d': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 12, 0), 'a': 2}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df[col] = pd.Series(df[col].dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype = object)
```

instead of

```
df[col] = df[col].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: seems likes this does make the columns to be `object` type, however it looks like doing `to_dict('records')` coerces it back to `Timestamp` while a simple `to_dict()` doesnt. i have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29824) on github

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
df["d"]=df.d.apply(lambda t: t.date())                                                                              
df.d.to_dict()                                                                                                      

{0: datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 1: datetime.date(2018, 1, 2)}
```

Comment: I lose the time information this way, which is not applicable for my use case. i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

somewhat relevant but if you want to dump data into a json, convert the dataframe into a json

```py
json_df = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

then output the data into a new json file

```py
with open('out.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json.loads(json_df), outfile)
```